# What is the better way to show a log in HTML showing the indentation?

Tags: javascript, html, console, gulp, console.log

I have an application with gulp task, in a certain task I have retire, like a security package, when I run this task with gulp, I get a log like this:

```
demo-mobile 1.1.5
  ↳ debowerify 1.3.1
    ↳ bower 1.3.12
      ↳ semver 2.3.2
```

I want to save this log in a html format but is not possible, when I run gulp, it saves in a html div.

```
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
 child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
 logInfo+= data;
});
```

The html template doesn't have indentation like the console.

```
demo-mobile-1.1.5-↳-debowerify-1.3.1-↳-bower-1.3.12-
```

Somebody have and idea how to fix this behavior.

Best Regards.

Comment: It works! What happen when your comment is my answer? Who win the vote?

Comment: nycynik seems to have the same answer, let them win ; ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there might be a better way, but how about:

```js
var input = "demo-mobile-1.1.5-↳-debowerify-1.3.1-↳-bower-1.3.12-";
var spaces = " ";
while (input.indexOf("-↳-") >0) {
 input = input.replace("-↳-", "<br>"+spaces+"↳"); 
  spaces += " ";
}

// below is just to show the output.
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
outputDiv.innerHTML = input;
```

```html
<div id="output" style="white-space: pre">


</div>
```